# Expression to calculate a field within a loop

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, expression

I basically have a few variables

```
0 < na < 250
0 < max <= 16
nb = (na + max - 1) / max
```

n has the following characterstics

```
0 <= i < nb - 1 => n = max
i = nb - 1 => n = na - i * max
```

Is there an easy way to do this without the ternary operator?

```
for (i = 0; i<nb;i++) {
    n = ((i + 1) * max > na ? na - (i * max) : max);
}
```

Examples

```
na = 5
max = 2
nb = 3

i = 0 => n = 2
i = 1 => n = 2
i = 2 => n = 1

na = 16
max = 4
nb = 4

i = 0 => n = 4
i = 1 => n = 4
i = 2 => n = 4
i = 3 => n = 4

na = 11
max = 3
nb = 4

i = 0 => n = 3
i = 1 => n = 3
i = 2 => n = 3
i = 3 => n = 2
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up 'i', 'na' and 'nb'. Please edit. and please make your actual question clearer.

Comment: what is your calculation? does your calculation change dependent on the interval i?

Comment: Atleast to me it's not clear what `n` is and how it's supposed to be calculated.

Comment: Your code (the example for loop) state that you want to calculate n, that supposed to be the same as nb?? also you are looping through nb in your first example, and you are using na and max in the second example, and not calculating anything (just printing data)... What are you trying to calculate??? (nb between na and max???? or nb from na until reaching max or what??)

Comment: `nb` is your dependent variable, and its possible values are in the range 0..250 assuming `max` starts at 1, or it'll also include infinity. now does `i` represent all the possible values `nb` can take? and what is `n`? how does it related to the `na`, `nb`, `max`?

Comment: @Anurag You're absolutely right both nb and max start at 1

Comment: Alright I wasn't quite clear at first, I hope it's better now.

Comment: +1 for so many revisions to clarify question

Comment: I felt that the question was clearer when it contained an example. I think three or four input/output examples would clarify the question much better than those formulas and example code do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not very clear. Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
for (i=0;i < nb;++i)
{ 
    n = i < nb - 1 ? max : (na - 1) % max + 1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It fails for "na = 12, max = 4" (gives 4,4,0 instead of 4,4,4). You can fix it with `int n = i < nb - 1 ? max : (na - 1) % max + 1;`.

Comment: @Mark: I think you are right. I didn't check all the corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate nb. This is one way you could do it (C#):

```
int na = 11;
int max = 4;

for (int i = 0, x = 0; x < na; i++, x += max)
{
     int n = Math.Min(max, na - x);
     Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, n = {1}", i, n);
}
```

Output:

```
i = 0, n = 4
i = 1, n = 4
i = 2, n = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more confusion to the thread:

If only you print max in the first two cases, then you could do something like: (not in any particular language)

```
//for 0
printf("i = %d, n = %d\n",i,max)
//for 1
printf("i = %d, n = %d\n",i,max)
//for the rest
for (i = 2; i<nb;i++) {
     printf("i = %d, n = %d\n",i,na - (i * max));
}
```

You can avoid the operator doing two for loops

```
for (i = 0; (i + 1) * max) > na AND i < nb;i++) {
     printf("i = %d, n = %d\n",i,0);
}
for (; i<nb;i++) {
     printf("i = %d, n = %d\n",i,na - (i * max));
}
```